# The property of being concave in all directions?

Tags: geometry

Is there a term for a shape being concave in all directions?  I recently got a new mandolin slicer and when I washed the hand guard, I noticed that it seemed to have this property.  No matter how I placed it on the drying rack, there was a concave surface facing up that will not drain.

The following shape is a 2D curve with with the 2D equivalent property.  No matter how it is rotated, there's a portion of its perimeter that is concave up.

[image]
[image]

A golf ball with deep dimples is another example.  No matter how you rotate it, a dimple will always be pointing close enough to up that it could catch water (ignoring surface tension)

It turns out there is an orientation in which there are no upward concavities for the hand guard, but not one which was stable in a drying rack.  So the hand guard is merely inspiration, not an example.

Comment: Until I come across a better term I'll be calling such shapes "non-draining".

Comment: Can you give a picture showing what you mean?

Comment: Does a golf ball also have the property you're thinking of, assuming the dimples are deep enough?

Comment: @DavidK Exactly, I was thinking of posting a picture of one, but given the shallowness of the dimples I was concerned it might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a simply closed, cusped plane curve with negative curvature...descriptive, but doesn't really roll of the tongue, now does it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be cusped.  The example I gave is, but the points could be rounded off and it would still have a section of curve that's concave facing in every direction.